# Not able to decode different image formats in GOLANG (assignment count mismatch)

Tags: image, go, compiler-errors, decode

I want to decode images of different formats and I'm running into problems calling `image.Decode`.

Here's my code and here's the error I'm seeing:

/myproject.go:21: assignment count mismatch: 2 = 3

```
package main

import (
 "fmt"
 "image"
 "log"
 "os"
)

func check(e error) {
 if e != nil {
     log.Fatal(e)
 }
}

func loadanddeconde(filename string) image.Image {
  reader, err := os.Open(filename)
  check(err)
  defer reader.Close()

/*21.line*/  img, err := image.Decode(reader)
  check(err)
  return img
  }

func main() {
 img := loadanddeconde("/home/gomok/Bureau/JSK.jpg")
 fmt.Printf("IMAGE TYPE: %T \n", img)
}
```

Comment: `image.Decode` should autodetect the format.  I'm not sure what you're asking.  What's web.go line 21?

Comment: Yes, normally it's autodetect the format.

Comment: web.go line 21 is the error i have when i build my programme ( web.go is the name of my project) line 21

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So that's just the go compiler saying you're getting 3 values returned from `image.Decode` and you're only assigning 2 of them.

Do this:

```
img, format, err := image.Decode(reader)
fmt.Printf("Image Type: %s\n", format)
```